# Let $\alpha_k=1,2,...,10$ be the roots of the unity of order 11, $\alpha_k \neq 1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, roots, roots-of-unity

> Let $\alpha_k=1,2,...,10$ be the roots of the unity of order 11, $\alpha_k \neq 1$. Then compute the following sum:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{10}\frac{1-\overline{\alpha_k}}{1+\alpha_k}.$$

So what I did was I thought the roots o unity must be the roots of the polynomial:

$$f=x^{10}+x^{9}+x^{8}+...+1=0$$

so then $f=x^{11}-1=0\to x^{11}=1$ and found that

$$\alpha_k=(\cos(\frac{2k\pi}{11})+i\sin(\frac{2k\pi}{11}).$$

But just by putting them into the formula is not really pleasant to solve.. is there any other way than just calculating the sum "as is"?

Comment: "Roots of unity of order $11$" are roots of the polynomial $x^{11}-1$, not $x^{12}-1$.

Comment: Hint: If $\alpha_k$ is a root, what about $\bar{\alpha_k}$?

Comment: @Martigan It's conjugate is what I meant

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Okay, let me fix it in the question

Comment: @C.Cristi My hint was: what can you say about the rooticity (I know, barbarism!) of the conjugate of a root?

Comment: @Martigan Oh, my apologies, it's a root itself

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the general case.

Let $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_{n-1}$ be the $n$-th roots of unity different from $1$, where $n$ is odd to avoid division by zero.

Note that $\alpha$ is an $n$-th root of unity iff $\overline{\alpha}$ is an $n$-th root of unity.

Pair the terms as follows:
$$
\frac{1-\overline{\alpha_k}}{1+\alpha_k}+
\frac{1-\alpha_k}{1+\overline{\alpha_k}}
=
2-\alpha_k-\overline{\alpha_k}
$$
because $\overline{\alpha_k}=1/\alpha$.

Sum both sides to get
$$
2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1-\overline{\alpha_k}}{1+\alpha_k}=
2(n-1)-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\alpha_k-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\overline{\alpha_k}
=2(n-1)+2
=2n
$$
because $1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\alpha_k=0$ since there is no $x^{n-1}$ term in $x^n-1=0$.